# Restrict so users only view a certain part of website-Django

Tags: python, django, user-interface, django-views

I am using Django, and require certain 'trial' users only to activate a certain part of the website-any ideas on an efficient way to do this?

I was thinking about giving a paying customer a certain ID and linking this to the URL of the sites for permission.

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 3):

I'd use a view decorator like this:

```
def paying_only(view):
    def _decorated(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not is_paying(request.user):
            redirect('page_explaining_that_this_is_for_paying_users_only')
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _decorated

@paying_only
def some_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: I think decorator is a clean solution. I used a middleware in the past in order to retrict acces to a closed beta website.

Answer (score 2):

I decided to post my solution, I might even get some feedback. I have a middleware blocking request/responses on certain paths defined in settings, first the middleware:

```
import re
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class InvitationRequired(object):

    def process_response(self, request, response):

        if not settings.CLOSED_BETA_ACTIVE:
            return response

        if (hasattr(request, 'user')
                and hasattr(request.user, 'is_authenticated')
                and request.user.is_authenticated()):
            return response
        elif (request.path in
                settings.CLOSED_BETA_INVITATION_MIDDLEWARE_EXCEPTED_URIS):
            return response
        elif response.status_code < 200 or response.status_code >= 300:
            return response
        else:
            for regex in \
                settings.CLOSED_BETA_INVITATION_MIDDLEWARE_EXCEPTED_PATTERNS:
                if re.compile(regex).match(request.path):
                    return response

        return redirect(settings.CLOSED_BETA_INVITATION_MIDDLEWARE_REDIRECT)
```

In settings.py I have something like this:

```
CLOSED_BETA_ACTIVE = True

CLOSED_BETA_INVITATION_URL = '/invitation/'
CLOSED_BETA_INVITATION_MIDDLEWARE_REDIRECT = CLOSED_BETA_INVITATION_URL

CLOSED_BETA_INVITATION_MIDDLEWARE_EXCEPTED_PATTERNS = (
    r'^/api/v1/',
    r'^/static/',
    r'^/media/',
    r'^/admin/',
    r'^/registration/',
    r'^/',
)
```

Hope it's clear, at least it can give you a a different approach.

Comment: Something like this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a very wide-ranging question. One solution would be to store a `trial` flag on each user. On an authenticated request, check for `User.trial` in your controller (and probably view) and selectively allow/deny access to the endpoint or selectively render parts of the page.

If you wish to use built-in capabilities of Django, you could view 'trial' as a permission, or a user group.

Comment: It's hard to provide examples as this stuff is so dependent on your own code and circumstances. Look for examples of Django user permissions and groups.